# Javascript element name change reverting back to original

Tags: javascript, dom, onchange

JavaScript name change of cloned input element "terminal0" isn't saving and/or reverting back to original name after function ends. All other name/id changes work but first element name change reverts back after function completes. Even the first element "terminal0" id change works successfully. I've tested and confirmed name change does work before function exits by placing an alert(cTerm.name) at the end of it. Anyone know reason why name change isn't working for first input element?

```
<tr id="tr1">
<td id="tr1Td0">
Terminal <input type="checkbox" name="terminal0" id="terminal0" value="0" onClick="cbUpdate()">
<br>
Imager <input type="checkbox" name="imager0" id="imager0" value="0" onClick="cbUpdate()">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

function addTable()
{
    var gssTable = document.getElementById("gssTable");
    var currTables = gssTable.rows[0].cells.length;
    var selNum = document.getElementById("sNum").value;
    var tr0 = document.getElementById("tr0");
    var tr1 = document.getElementById("tr1");
    var br = document.createElement('br');

    for(x=currTables; x < selNum; x++)
    {
        var tr0Td0 = tr0.insertCell(-1);
        var setID0 = document.getElementById("setID0");
        var cSetID = setID0.cloneNode(true);
        cSetID.id = "setID" + x;
        cSetID.name = "setID" + x;
        tr0Td0.appendChild(cSetID);

        var tr1Td0 = tr1.insertCell(-1);
        tr1Td0.innerHTML="Terminal";
        var terminal0 = document.getElementById("terminal0");
        var cTerm = terminal0.cloneNode(true);
        cTerm.id = "test" + x;
        cTerm.name = "test" + x;
        tr1Td0.appendChild(cTerm);
        tr1Td0.appendChild(br);
        tr1Td0.innerHTML = tr1Td0.innerHTML + "Imager"
        var imager0 = document.getElementById("imager0");
        var cImager = imager0.cloneNode(true);
        cImager.id = "imager" + x;
        cImager.name = "imager" + x;
        tr1Td0.appendChild(cImager);
    }

    while (currTables > selNum)
    {
        tr1.deleteCell(-1);
        tr0.deleteCell(-1);

        currTables = currTables - 1;
    }
```

Comment: Could you make an executable snippet or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Instead of setting the innerHTML, each time, you could just create a text node and appendChild it, ie `tr1Td0.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Imager"))`

Comment: I tried to make a jsfiddle example but I'm using coldfusion and it doesn't seem to be acting correctly because of it. Basically the problem is that the 1st input name isn't changing like everything else is and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the innerHTML makes the browser re-render that element and its contents. Since you are doing it each iteration of the loop, you are probably causing a race condition where innerHTML hasn't been updated to the latest effects of the appendChild calls above it.

So instead of setting innerHTML each time you can just create a [Text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text), with [createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode), and append it.

```
tr1Td0.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Imager"));
```

Comment: TY @PatrickEvans for explaining the logic behind why your original solution worked. That means a lot to me. TYTY